# Java - Product Trader Specification class?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I'm looking in this example for product trader: http://www.eli.sdsu.edu/courses/spring98/cs635/notes/builder/builder.html (it's second example. First one is Builder pattern). And I got a bit confused. In class diagram it shows `Specification` as different class, but in example I don't see such class and it looks like Specification class' methods were created in ProductTrader class. Am I mistaken? If there would be standard example of Product Trader pattern, how Specification class would look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example you posted the specification is the String that gets passed into the create method.  I've never seen this pattern before so I'm unaware of a standard example.  Another example would be a file-to-image trader where the specification is a file and the result is an image created from that file (you could have a PNG creator, a JPG creator, etc.)

```
public interface ProductTrader<P, S> {

  public P create(S specification);

}

public interface ImageCreator {

  public boolean canProcess(File file);

  public Image createImage(File file);

}

public class PNGImageCreator implements ImageCreator {

  public boolean canProcess(File file) {
    return (file.isFile() && file.canRead() && file.getName().endsWith(".png"));
  }

  public Image createImag(File file) {
    //Image I/O code goes here
  }

}

public class FileToImageProductTrader implements ProductTrader<Image, File> {

  private List<ImageCreator> imageCreators = new ArrayList<ImageCreator>();

  public void registerCreator(ImageCreator creator) {
    imageCreators.add(creator);
  }

  public Image create(File specification) {
    for(ImageCreator creator : imageCreators) {
      if(creator.canProcess(specification)) {
        return creator.createImage(specification);
      }
    }
    //No creator for given file
    return null;
  }

}

public class Main {

  public static void main(String [] args) {
    FileToImageProductTrader trader = new FileToImageProductTrader();
    PNGCreator pngCreator = new PNGCreator();
    trader.registerCreator(pngCreator);
    File imageFile = new File("/tmp/foo.png");
    Image image = trader.create(imageFile);
  }

}
```

Comment: Maybe you have a link where I could see that example with image creator, where specification is used as a file?

Comment: I made that example up, but I can add it to my answer.

Comment: You might also take a look at the Java [ImageIO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html) class which is a product trader similar to the one I described.  The specification is either a File, ImageInputStream, InputStream, or URL and the creators are [ImageReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageReader.html)s